# How to write multi-level (bullet) lists in a table using rmarkdown and pandoc

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, pander

I am looking to create a table in a PDF document using `rmarkdown`, `knitr` and `pander`. I am able to create a [simple bullet list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011265/how-to-write-bullet-lists-in-a-table-using-rmarkdown-and-pandoc) but now require another level in that list. In the table shown below, I require the "Rave reviews" bullet to be a sub-bullet of the "Offers workshops..." bullet.

[image: multibullet]

The issue I'm having pertains to the line of code below in the `mytable` dataframe in the `Description` column. Although I attempt to create the 4 spaces required for a sub-bullet using `\x20`[1], those spaces do not appear - and hence no sub-bullets (although no error is shown). I also tried the most obvious way of simply adding in 4 spaces in the code to no avail. Also attempted to set my `R` options to include `strip.white = FALSE`, but that has also not proven helpful (see below).

````
---
title: "xxx"
author: "xxx"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_height: 4
    fig_width: 10
    highlight: tango
  word_document: default
geometry: margin=3cm
---

```{r global_options, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
require(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.width=8, fig.height=4, fig.path='figs/', dpi=500,
               echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='hide', strip.white = FALSE)
```

```{r pandoc_options, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
require(pander)
panderOptions('digits', 3)
panderOptions('round', 3)
panderOptions('keep.trailing.zeros', TRUE)
panderOptions('keep.line.breaks', TRUE)
```

```{r concepts, echo=FALSE}
mytable = data.frame(
    Concept     = c("Decoded", "XXX"),
    Description = c("* Founded in 2011\ \n* Offers workshops to take people from zero skills and knowledge in programming through to coding a multi-platform app using HTML, CSS and Javascript in a single day\ \n\x20\x20\x20\x20+ Rave reviews", "XXX"),
    Website     = c("http://decoded.com/uk/","XXX"))
```

``` {r concepts_descriptions, results = 'asis'}
pander::pander(mytable, keep.line.breaks = TRUE, style = 'grid', justify = 'left')
```
````

#### References

[1] I got the `\x20` hint from [here](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/blank-space-escape-sequence-in-R-td3473104.html), after attempting `\\s`, `\s`, `\ \s`, `\\\s`, etc. to no avail (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992082/how-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-a-string)).

Comment: @bergant thanks - unfortunately pdf creation is stopped ("Execution is halted") if I try putting in `\hspace{10pt}`. Also tried playing with `` to no avail. Could you please elaborate on what you meant in the parentheses?

Comment: Sorry I checked and it doesn't work in this case - that is why I deleted the comment. About the error: to use the \hspace in constant string use \\hspace (double backslash)

Comment: About the white-space removal in `pander`: it is necessary so that the `justify` (align) parameter could work. Unfortunately there's no easy workaround for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest the items inside the bullet:

````
```{r concepts, echo=FALSE}
mytable = data.frame(
    Concept     = c("Decoded", "XXX"),
    Description = c("* Founded in 2011\ \n
    * Offers workshops to take people from zero skills and knowledge in programming through to coding a multi-platform app using HTML, CSS and Javascript in a single day\ \n
    \\begin{itemize}
      \\item Rave reviews \n
      \\item e.t.c
    \\end{itemize}", "XXX"),
    Website     = c("http://decoded.com/uk/","XXX"))
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I didn't realize you were using a pdf, but here is an html solution

1. I would use a matrix
2. I would use the htmlTable package which allows for much more advanced tables than kable or pander

First make a wrapper for your lists

```
make_list <- function(...) {
  paste0("<ul>", sprintf('<li>%s</li>', substitute(...())), '</ul>', collapse = '')
}

make_list(one, two, three)

# [1] "<ul><li>one</li></ul><ul><li>two</li></ul><ul><li>three</li></ul>"


library('htmlTable')
mytable <- matrix(c("Decoded", "XXX",
                    make_list('Founded in 2011', 'Offers workshops to take people from zero skills and knowledge in programming through to coding a multi-platform app using HTML, CSS and Javascript in a single day','Rave reviews'),
                    "XXX",
                    "http://decoded.com/uk/","XXX"), 2,
                  dimnames = list(NULL, c('Concept','Description','Website')))

htmlTable(mytable, align = 'lll')
```

[image]

This is fine but the vertical align is bad and the boxes are too wide. But we can fix with one of the css parameters of `htmlTable`. vertical align pushes the text to the top rather than center, max-width sets the text wrapping, and auto width lets each have its own width

```
htmlTable(mytable, align = 'lll', align.header = 'lll',
          css.cell = "width: auto; max-width: 250px; vertical-align: top;")
```

[image]